# Given a map $f : \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{N},$ prove that $f$ is injective.

Tags: functions, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm

The full question: Define a map $f : \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{N}$ by $f(x) = (z, n)$ if $x = \frac{z}{n} \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\gcd(z,n) = 1$ for $z \neq 0$. Prove that $f$ is injective.

Here is my proof:

*Proof*: Let $x = \frac{z}{n}$ and $x' = \frac{z'}{n'}$. Suppose $f(x) = f(x')$. This means that $(z', n') = (z, n)$ which implies that $z' = z$ and $n = n'$. Hence, $x = x'$ and thus, $f$ is injective. QED.

Is this valid? I understand that $\gcd(z, n)$ in the question means we take a rational number that is fully reduced but am not sure why we need to use it in the proof.

(EDITED): added in $x = x' \dots$

Any help is great! Thanks

Comment: Your title has "surjective" but your post has "injective"......

Comment: You're very close, but the ending needs a slight tweak. Remember, your goal is $f(x) = f(x') \to x = x'.$ So you just need one more step.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks. Sorry about that. :(

Comment: @StephenDonovan, Oh...Are you indicating I forgot to say "which implies that $x = x'$ at the end?

Comment: You need to have rational numbers written in reduced form for the map to be well-defined.

Comment: @Owen Yeah, basically. Like I said, it's slight but it is nice to have your conclusion actually written at the end of the proof. And as Bernard indicated, the fact that you didn't use $\gcd(z, n) = 0$ doesn't indicate that you're wrong, that's there because otherwise we don't have a function, since one input could give infinitely many outputs.

Comment: @StephenDonovan I, see! That makes sense! Thank you!